# How to convert global ID to app scope ID

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have worked on admin system for my company's game. There are a page we opened to let user report problem. However the new system of facebook make us confuse with userID which changed for each app but the page still show only real facebook userID, which often differ from app scope ID

I want to know a way to convert real userID to app scope ID programmatically

Are there anyway to did it?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 5):

You cannot just convert real IDs to scoped IDs, but:

- The ID will always stay the same in one app, only new users will get a scoped id when the app gets upgraded to v2.x
- If you need to link users between different apps, use the Business Mapping API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business

Comment: I don't need these info. I need to convert this because my page admin can only get real user ID

Comment: i know, but converting is not possible afaik. what you want to do would make the whole system with the app scoped id void.

Comment: It is possible though. See my answer. What would make the whole system void, is if you could convert app scoped user IDs to global IDs, and not the other way around.

Comment: please comment if you downvote. my question is 100% correct, but if you think there should be any improvement, let me know.

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to retrieve the app scoped user IDs, though it's a little bit quirky.

Using an access token which is *not* for the user that you want the app scoped ID for, fetch the user(s) with the global ID using the URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/?ids=[COMMA SEPARATED LIST OF USER IDS]&fields=link
```

The response will then be in the following format:

```
{
  "700230415": {
    "link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/10158562170695476/", 
    "id": "700230415"
  }, 
  "700634149": {
    "link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/10152566310960142/", 
    "id": "700634149"
  },
}
```

Then you can parse the `link` field to get the app scoped IDs.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "convert" global user_ids to app-scoped ones. As you didn't describe what your "admin system" does exactly, it's nearly impossible to give you a suggestion.

Probably, your "admin system" uses an app with is using Graph API v1.0 (i.e. created before April 30th 2014). That's why you still see global user_ids.

It's possible to prepend `/v2.0` to the requests, which should give you app-scoped user_ids, but this doesn't help you much, because they are different for each app. As @luschn described, you can use the Business Mapping API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business) to get all app-scoped user_ids for a specific user.

Comment: I already describe that it is "Page" of facebook sorry if it is ambiguous. User would come chat for anykind of problem however my admin person would grab user id who come in contact to me. I know how to use ids_for_business for so long but it can't work in this kind of scenario

Comment: It can't be a page, probably you mean a page tab **app**. Still, you don't confirm whether your "admin system" uses v1.0 or not

Comment: Page chat system has nothing to do with fbapi version. Simply put it still stuck with old version of facebook. And the admin system use the same appID and signature of real app so the problem is conflict

Comment: I give up, as I don't understand what you're talking about. As said, converting global user_ids into app-scoped ones is not possible.

Answer (score -1):

If you want convert Global ID to Scope ID, I think you should know:

- Scope ID for Facebook API Ver 2.x
- One Global ID connect with an App will have a Scope ID. It mean if you have one hundred separate App, each one Global ID have one hundred Scope ID from each App