# Translating public Facebook id to app-scoped id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

For the past year we've used the link-parsing trick ([How to convert global ID to app scope ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25493337/how-to-convert-global-id-to-app-scope-id)) to convert our app's public FB id's to app-scoped ids. However, it now appears that Facebook has changed something under their hood, since the id visible in the link-field now points back to the public id and not the app-scoped one. According to Graph API Explorer, the behavior is the same in all Graph API 2.x -versions. This change in behavior is also very recent.

So, anyone aware of an alternative method of doing this now?

Comment: _“since the id visible in the link-field now points back to the public id and not the app-scoped one”_ – can’t confirm that, I get the same ids in the `link` field as the app-scoped user id. Anyway, your app is not really supposed to handle data of just “random” users, but rather only of users that have connected to your app – so why would you need the connection between the ”real” and the app-scoped user id anyway? Your app is supposed to make do with the latter.

Comment: Exactly. Now the id is the same, but previously it always got translated to the app-scoped one. Our app itself only deals with the app-scoped ids but I'm working on a supporting tool that's used to look up our user's accounts by their public FB ids.

Comment: _“look up our user's accounts by their public FB ids”_ – that is not supposed to be possible any more. Have users login to your app, then you have their app-scoped id.

Comment: Our users do log in to our app and internally we're using app-scoped ids since the beginning. However, there are certain customer support related use cases, where the only thing available is the public id and the ability to translate it to app scoped id has been very useful.

Comment: The support flows in Facebook's UI should provide the user with their app scoped ID for your app for that use-case - are your instructions for your users when asking for their user ID up to date?

Comment: If our users can't access the app for whatever reason, they will have no means to get to their app-scoped id.